# How do I wrap a string with asterisks to give it *emphasis* without making the text italic?

Tags: discussion, markdown

I realize asterisks are used on SO to make text *italic*, but sometimes I want to actually *print* the asterisks, for aesthetic or dramatic effect.

**EDIT #2:**

Following meagar's suggestion below, I remembered the `<em>` tag (lol), which works perfectly:

```
\*<em>hi</em>\*
```

...produces...

> **hi**

---

*(Original text:)*

So far I've come up with

```
*`*emphasis*`*
```

This produces "*`*emphasis*`*"... which doesn't look too great.

EDIT: Escaping asterisks (as per "\*" to get "*") works great, but as an aside, if I try to do

```
\**extra emphasis*\*
```

I get

> **extra emphasis**

...is this a parser bug? If I do

```
*\*extra emphasis*\*
```

I get

> **extra emphasis**

...yet if you look closely, the opening asterisk is italic, whereas the closing one is normal. (Another bug!)

I can only do italics *and* visible asterisks if I do

```
*\*extra emphasis\**
```

Which gives me

> **extra emphasis**

But that leaves the asterisks italic, which looks utterly icky to me.

Comment: ... What gives a word more emphasis than `<em>` tags?

Comment: Aha! That did it (edited OP). Thanks!

Comment: Looking at your question above (and the HTML source of this page), `\**extra emphasis*\*` seems to produce the HTML output `*<em>extra emphasis</em>*`, just as if you'd typed `\*<em>extra emphasis</em>\*` in the first place. What else are you seeing (or expecting)?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but this post seems to have generated a pile of new traffic within the past 2-3 days (about a day ago it was at 89 views, where it had been for ages, I'm guessing.) I have absolutely no idea where my head was when I was asking all this, I recognize that I bodged most of the syntax horribly. I've updated the question to reflect as such. Thanks for the interest!

Comment: If you have a new issue, you're probably better off asking a new question than continuing to add on to this old one... you can certainly link here for reference but editing your question can often invalidate your answers... and I don't understand why you're asking for info on why this question is getting traffic as part of your question.

Comment: Honestly, your last two edits look more like **answers** than additional questions... if you have **solutions** to your question, you should post them as **answers** not add them as random text in your question.

Comment: I don't have a new issue. This question is from 2014, and out of the blue got upvoted twice within the last two days, with its view count (which I knew to be 89 yesterday) has gone up by 20 views. In light of this extra activity, I'm pointing out that the majority of the question is now invalid so that people don't waste their time reading through it to answer it. However, I'm not *removing* the question because, as you said, I don't want to invalidate the answers on this page.

Comment: If moving the answers down is the canonical solution then I'll do that, but I've seen other answers edited similarly to this, and I appreciate that they mean I can do less reading.

Comment: Where? Answers **do not** go in a question... answers go in **answers**.

Comment: Okay then, thanks for the help. I'm admittedly still quite new to how things are done around here :D

Comment: ...I just realized I didn't accept the posted answer from two years ago (?!?), which I've done now. Since it does actually answer my question, adding a new answer is not going to help; I've removed the answers from my question. To anybody reading this wondering what's going on, see the question's answer history to make sense of these comments.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just escape the asterisks with a backslash `\`.

```
\*emphasis\*
```

Produces:

> *emphasis*

Comment: \* *facepalm* \* :P Thanks!