# Is this bug or any special method to write a post using special character?

Tags: support, markdown, markdown-preview

When I try to use underscore in my post, sometimes the preview displays my text in italics with no underscore. That confused me, and I have placed two underscores. Now the preview does not show the actual preview. For example, if I add underscore before the text, the text displayed normal text enclosed by a single star. (i.e. **BOLD** *_italic* *italic*)

[image]

However, I don't know how to use * in my text if it is used to define italic text. (i.e. *ABC).  How do I use underscores and asterisks in the Stack Exchange editor literally?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I wrap a string with asterisks to give it \*emphasis\* without making the text italic?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221615/how-do-i-wrap-a-string-with-asterisks-to-give-it-emphasis-without-making-the-t)

Comment: @MartijnPieters have checked my old question before editing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

_This is a test_

Here's what I'm typing to get this result:

```
\_This is a test\_
```

To use reserved characters in their literal form, simply escape them with a backslash. For an '*', I simply escape it:

```
\* <-- Escaped asterisk
```

Comment: should i change the tag if it is not a bug?